# Button is not responsive on headerview of UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, header, uibutton

I am creating headers for my tableview.And adding view on that header.
In that view there are two imageviews and a button

The button is not responsive(a very small area on the top part is responsive)
Why this is happening,Please help me ?

I have tried with some SO answers- like "setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingNone"
But nothing is working

Here is my code

```
 -(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {


  // ADDING A VIEW     

   UIView *header = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 310, 39.0)];
   header.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
   header.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
  [header setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];


  // ADDING IMAGE VIEW

    UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 310, 39.0)];
    image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"headertop.png"];
    [image setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];
    [header addSubview:image];


  // ADDING ANOTHER IMAGEVIEW (beneath the view's frame)

    UIImageView *downImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0 , 39, 310, 23)];
    downImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"headerbottom.png"];
   [header addSubview:downImage];




 // ADDING BUTTON


  UIButton *placeBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
  [placeBtn addTarget:self
             action:@selector(goToRestPage:)
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   placeBtn.tag = section;
   placeBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

   placeBtn.frame = CGRectMake(75,20, 150, 20);
   [header addSubview:placeBtn];





     return header;

  }
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this Method. I think you miss this method.

```
-(float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
     return  30.0;
}
```

Or this method already exists so increase the height of the header.

```
-(float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
     return  80.0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do this :

User Interaction Enabled to TRUE from your XIB. by default its FALSE.

Thanks,

Comment: on which...??

I am creating everything programmatically
In XIB there is just table view

Comment: what is your header height ?